# How do I access the cell content of a pure html table from asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a table:

```
<table id="trTable" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none">
                    ID
                </th>
                <th style="width: 112px">
                    Item
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40px; text-align: left">
                    Price
                </th>
                <th style="width: 24px; text-align: center">
                </th>
                <th style="width: 26px; text-align: center">
                    Qty
                </th>
                <th style="width: 24px; text-align: center">
                </th>
                <th style="width: 40px; text-align: right">
                    Total
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and new rows are added to it with jQuery:

```
var newRow = $("<tr> <td class='drinkID' style='display:none'>" + drinkID + "</td> <td class='drinkName'>" + dName + "</td>  <td class='drinkPrice'>" + dPrice + "</td>  <td style='text-align:center'><input id='Button' type='button' value='<' class='minusButton' /> </td>  <td class='drinkQty'>1</td>  <td style='text-align:center'><input id='Button' type='button' value='>' class=\"plusButton\" /></td>  <td class='drinkTotal'>" + dPrice + "</td>  </tr>");
```

How do I access the content of the cells using asp.net?

I am using:

```
foreach (HtmlTableRow row in trTable.Rows)
        {
            Response.Write("RowDetails:" + row.Cells[1].InnerHtml);
        }
```

But the response.write just outputs:

```
RowDetails: Item
```

How come it doesn't get the cell contents?

Comment: as i know it is because of security restriction behind ASP.NET.i think as you made change to a server control ASP.NET don't allow this change to be submitted to the server.

Answer (score 2):

What you change on the html struct page, on client side, is not send back on the server, and sever know nothing about.

With other words, what is on the page, is not fully sanded back on the server.

To solve this, you can make at the same time two edits, one on what user see and one hidden on a hidden input, to post back to the server the changes and recreate the table on the server side.

Hope this make scene.

Comment: Does this mean I have to post the form back each time a row is added?

Comment: @Ben Yes, there is not other way, maybe each time a row added for autosave, or a save button to send them all back.

Comment: @Ben Or not use javasrcript and jquery, but do that with asp.net buttons and commands. Eg, by pressing a button, you make a post back, and there you add your row - and server now know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Microsoft Ajax enabling partial rendering on in the row. This will do the same postback effect but will only send the afffected content to the client side.